# Laravel artisan not creating all columns

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, laravel-artisan, octobercms

When OctoberCMS creates this table, it only has the id column.

I can not figure out why.

Here is the class from my updates/createTable.php file.

```
class CreateCellphoneTable extends Migration
{

  public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('iaff106_cell_phones', function($table)
    {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('label')->nullable();
        $table->string('phone')->index();
        $table->integer('provider_id')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('cantxt')->default(true);
        $table->boolean('published')->default(false);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
  }
}
```

I am executing artisan like this:

```
php artisan plugin:refresh IAFF106.CellPhone
```

Comment: what columns created, and what not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that Artisan is not very good about reporting problems like a misspelled PHP file for instance.

I had misspelled the createTable.php file in my version.yaml file.  Artisan was not doing anything even though it did not complain and it all looked ok.

The combination of anand patel's answer and me coming back for a fresh look helped me find this.

Comment: In version.yaml first line is for version comment if you have specified first line as database migration file then there is no effect of artisan command.http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#migrations-version-history

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code its create all fields

have you imported all classes that required

here is my code for createTable.php

```
<?php namespace IAFF106\CellPhone\Updates;
use Schema;
use October\Rain\Database\Updates\Migration;
class CreateCellphoneTable extends Migration
{

    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('iaff106_cell_phones', function($table)
        {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
            $table->string('label')->nullable();
            $table->string('phone')->index();
            $table->integer('provider_id')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('cantxt')->default(true);
            $table->boolean('published')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

and code in version.yaml is

```
1.0.1:
      - First version of CellPhone
      - createTable.php
```

[image]

i hope you have specify createTable.php in version.yaml file

Comment: I didn't know is it worth enough to getting this type of error.I tried all the suggestion here but can't get rid of it.Then I tried to run the code in my IDE(Netbeans),Just click the green arrow run button.Then `php artisan migrate` commnad and it works.I dont know why he closed the question.it needs more answer

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens when you have a duplicate column inside of your up() function, double-check your columns just to be sure.